# How Does NSArray Operate? When compared to Java's ArrayList

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to get the equivalents for an NSArray when compared to Java ArrayList?

However, what I'm trying to do (learning Objective-C at the minute) is have a NSArray of 6 integers. Allow myself to 'index' into specific point of these integers and set an integer. Then check if the NSArray is null or zero, if not then loop through and print out integers to some label on screen (example).

Is this possible? The documentation isn't the best at all it seems. Though I am finding Apple's tutorials on general iPhone development extremely useful!

Answer (score 5):

For what you want to do, the main differences between an implementation of `java.util.List` and `NSArray` are:

- Objective-C doesn't have "autoboxing", so you can't just pass a number like 3 to the array and have it store the correct object. You have to explicitly wrap it yourself in an instance of `NSNumber`, by doing `[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]`
- any implementation of `List` may optionally implement the `.add()` and `.remove()` API. In Foundation, there is a subclass of `NSArray` that allows you to change its content, called `NSMutableArray`.
- Objective-C doesn't have generics, so you can't do the equivalent of `List<String>`

Other than that, `List` and `NSArray` are quite similar: each is abstract, telling you how you can use an implementing object but not enforcing the way that object works. For example, an `ArrayList` is implemented using an array, but `NSArray` chooses an appropriate implementation dynamically based on the content you try to use.

Comment: I know your answer was from 2010, so I want to add something new for people who are visiting in 2013. The Objective-C programming language has improved. You can use the new literal syntax for boxing: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html